How to auto-complete variables in VS Code without typing the $ symbol?
In VS Code, how can I make variable names auto-complete without typing the $ symbol? For example, when I type data, it should automatically suggest and complete it as $data. When I used IntelliJ IDEA before, it worked like this. How can I achieve the same behavior in VS Code?
I have already installed PHP Intelephense ext

How should it know you do not mean a keyword instead of a variable?

@MarkusZeller In most languages, variables don't start with a special character, yet auto-completion does work.

It seems PHP IntelliSense extension works better and might be more suitable in your case than PHP Intelephense extension. At least from its homepage, it seems it could help you autocomplete without $. There are couple of examples on how to using the extension.
